# Java program terminated before running

Tags: java, debugging

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TicTacToe {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        board b = new board();

        while (!b.detectWin('x') && !b.detectWin('o') && !b.detectTie()) {
            b.printBoard();
            System.out.println("Player 1, where do you want to put an x?");
                    int xAnswer = input.nextInt();
                    b.setSpot('x', xAnswer);

                    b.printBoard();
                    System.out.println("Player 2, where do you want to put an o?");
                    int oAnswer = input.nextInt();
                    b.setSpot('o',  oAnswer);
b.printBoard();
        if(b.detectWin('x')) {
            System.out.println("Player 1 won!");
        }else if (b.detectWin('o')) {
            System.out.println("Player 2 won!");
        }else {
            System.out.println("There was a tie.");
        }
            }
        }
    }
```

It's a tic tac toe program, here's the board:

```
public class board {
    private char[] board;

    public board() {
        board = new char[]
                {'0', '1', '2',
                '3', '4', '5',
                '6', '7', '8'};
                }
    public void setSpot(char player, int position) {
        if (board[position] == position+48) {
            board[position] = player;
        }else {
            System.out.println("Incorrect move, turn skipped");
        }
    }

    public boolean detectWin(char player){
        if((board[0] == player && board[1] == player && board[2] == player) 
|| (board[3] == player && board[4] == player && board[5] == player) || 
(board[6] == player && board[7] == player && board[8] == player) || 
(board[0] == player && board[3] == player && board[6] == player) || 
(board[1] == player && board[4] == player && board[7] == player) || 
(board[2] == player && board[5] == player && board[8] == player) || 
(board[0] == player && board[4] == player && board[8] == player) || 
(board[2] == player && board[4] == player && board[6] == player))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    public boolean detectTie() {
        for (int i = 0; i > board.length; i++) {
            if (board[i] == i+48)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void printBoard() {
        System.out.println(board[0] + " | " +board[1] +" | " +board[2]);
        System.out.println("---------");
        System.out.println(board[3] + " | " + board[4] + " | " + board[5]);
        System.out.println("--------");
        System.out.println(board[6] + " | " + board [7] + " | " + board[8]);

    }
}
```

It keeps getting terminated, and I can't find out why. No error messages.

(placeholder for post is mostly code error placeholder for post is mostly code error placeholder for post is mostly code error placeholder for post is mostly code error placeholder for post is mostly code error

Comment: As you seem to know from the tag you included, a debugger would be invaluable right now, because it would likely reveal the exact line of code which is failing.  Add a breakpoint in your IDE and debug your code.

Comment: Check your method: `detectTie()` it doesn't do what you think it's doing

Answer (score 0):

simple typo in your code, change detectTie as follows:

```
public boolean detectTie() {
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        if (board[i] == i+48)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

and you should be good. you were using int i = 0; i > board.length; i++, so i was starting with 0, and that was not greater than the board arrays length so it never executed the loop and just returned true, this in turn caused !b.detectTie() to return false, meaning the main while loop was never executed.